# Show a text on the middle of the page - Vaadin

Tags: java, gwt, vaadin

I'm learning vaadin and have a problem to show a text (label) on the middle of the page
Can someone explain why this code does not work?

```
Window window=new Window();

VerticalLayout root=new VerticalLayout();
root.setSizeFull();

Label c=new Label("User name");
//TextField c=new TextField("User name");

root.addComponent(c);
root.setComponentAlignment(c, Alignment.MIDDLE_CENTER);

window.setContent(root);
setMainWindow(window);
```

If to use TextField instead of Label, then everything is fine.
So what is wrong with Label?

Answer (score 9):

The width of a Label is 100% by default so your Label is centered but it takes all available space horizontally. You can fix this by saying:

```
c.setWidth(null);
```

or

```
c.setSizeUndefined();
```

Comment: You are right. Chapter 5.4 of the book of vaadin describes that.